# Create React App CSS autoprefixer breaking flexbox in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, safari, flexbox

From create-react-app's readme @ https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

becomes

```
.App {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

In practice, after running yarn build, it becomes:

```
.App {
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -ms-flex-direction:row;
  flex-direction:row;
  -ms-flex-align:center;
  align-items:center
}
```

I believe this missing -webkit- is breaking my websites in Safari. Does anyone know how this can be prevented or if I am doing anything incorrectly?  Thank you.

Comment: If you see issues please file them in the repository. Then we can fix them :-)

Comment: Do you mean to post a new issue here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues ?  I'm not sure if it's user error on my side, intended by the developers, or a bug.